# remove border and add multilevel submenu

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

## test.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.core.window import Window



class CustDrop(DropDown):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustDrop, self).__init__( **kwargs)
        self.select('')




class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ =='__main__':
    ExampleApp().run()
```

## test.kv

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    #spacing : 10
    BoxLayout:
        #spacing : 10
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

            #Color:
                #rgb: (70,70,70)

        size_hint_y:1
        Button:
            spacing : 10
            text: 'test1'
            size : (60,30)
            size_hint : (None, None)
            background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
            color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1



        Button:
            text: 'test2'
            size: (60, 30)
            size_hint: (None, None)
            background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
            color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1

        Button:
            id: btn
            text: 'test3'
            size: (60, 30)
            size_hint: (None, None)
            on_release: dropdown.open(self)
            #size_hint_y: None
            #height: '40dp'
            background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
            color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1

        CustDrop:

            id: dropdown

            Button:
                text: 'Sub menu1 Test3'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '30dp'
                #on_release: dropdown.select('')
                on_release: app.root.test
                background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
                color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1

            Button:
                text: 'Sub menu2 Test3'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '30dp'
                on_release: dropdown.select('')
                background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
                color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1


            Button:
                text: 'Sub menu3 Test3'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '30dp'
                on_release: dropdown.select('')
                background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
                color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1

            Button:
                text: 'Fourth'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '30dp'
                on_release: dropdown.select('')
                background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
                color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1

    BoxLayout:

        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

            Color:
                rgb: (1,1,1)

        AsyncImage
            source: '2.jpg'

        AsyncImage
            source: '4.jpg'

        AsyncImage
            source: '2.jpg'

        Label:
            size_hint_x: 22

    Label:
        size_hint_y: 18
```

1. I want to have only right border in menu (Test1,Test2,Test3)
2. When click on 'Test3' menu then show submenu.I want to increase width Of submenu and all menu should left align.
3. How to add multilevel submneu in Test3 menu
4. In second row decrease space between image 4.jpg and 2.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to have only right border in menu (Test1,Test2,Test3)

You can set each `background_normal` to `''` then draw the borders yourself in their canvas

> When click on 'Test3' menu then show submenu.I want to increase width Of submenu and all menu should left align.

You must set the `auto_width` property of your `DropDown` to `False` then set the `width` you want

> How to add multilevel submneu in Test3 menu

Like the first you must attach the other `DropDown` to one child of the `DropDown`

> In second row decrease space between image 4.jpg and 2.jpg

you have just to set the `spacing` of the `BoxLayout`

Below is your code with all your requests :

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    #spacing : 10
    BoxLayout:
        #spacing : 10
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

            #Color:
                #rgb: (70,70,70)

        size_hint_y:1
        Button:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb: 0,0,0
                Line:
                    points: self.pos[0] + self.size[0], self.pos[1], self.pos[0] + self.size[0], self.pos[1] + self.size[1]
                    width: 1.5
            spacing : 10
            text: 'test1'
            size : (60,30)
            size_hint : (None, None)
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
            color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1



        Button:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb: 0,0,0
                Line:
                    points: self.pos[0] + self.size[0], self.pos[1], self.pos[0] + self.size[0], self.pos[1] + self.size[1]
                    width: 1.5
            text: 'test2'
            size: (60, 30)
            size_hint: (None, None)
            background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
            background_normal: ''
            color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1

        Button:

            id: btn
            text: 'test3'
            size: (60, 30)
            size_hint: (None, None)
            on_release: dropdown.open(self)
            #size_hint_y: None
            #height: '40dp'
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
            color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1

        CustDrop:
            auto_width: False
            size_hint_x: None
            width: '250dp'
            id: dropdown
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '30dp'
                Button:
                    text: 'Sub menu1 Test3'
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: '125dp'
                    #on_release: dropdown.select('')
                    on_release: app.root.test
                    background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
                    color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
                Button:
                    background_color: 0,0,0,0
                    width: '125dp'
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '30dp'
                Button:
                    text: 'Sub menu2 Test3'
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: '125dp'
                    on_release: dropdown.select('')
                    background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
                    color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
                Button:
                    background_color: 0,0,0,0
                    width: '125dp'
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '30dp'
                Button:
                    text: 'Sub menu3 Test3'
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: '125dp'
                    on_release: dropdown.select('')
                    background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
                    color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
                Button:
                    background_color: 0,0,0,0
                    width: '125dp'
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '30dp'
                Button:
                    text: 'Fourth'
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: '125dp'
                    on_release: dropdown2.open(d2)
                    background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
                    color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
                Button:
                    id: d2
                    background_color: 0,0,0,0
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: self.parent.width/2.0
                CustDrop:
                    auto_width: False
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: '125dp'
                    id: dropdown2
                    Button:
                        text: 'Sub menu1 Test3'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: '30dp'
                        #on_release: dropdown2.select('')
                        on_release: app.root.test
                        background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
                        color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1

                    Button:
                        text: 'Sub menu2 Test3'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: '30dp'
                        on_release: dropdown2.select('')
                        background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
                        color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1


                    Button:
                        text: 'Sub menu3 Test3'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: '30dp'
                        on_release: dropdown2.select('')
                        background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
                        color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 0,0
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

            Color:
                rgb: (1,1,1)

        AsyncImage
            source: '2.jpg'

        AsyncImage
            source: '4.jpg'

        AsyncImage
            source: '2.jpg'

        Label:
            size_hint_x: 22

    Label:
        size_hint_y: 18
```

## Update add sub sub menu in front

to do this I put each button of the sub menu in box the I add another invisible button in the same box it is that invisible button which gone be attached to the sub sub menu

I hope this helps !

Comment: thanks for reply.Can you give me one more favour? when i click on fourth then submenu show  under fourth menu.how to show in front of fourth

Comment: @yashkumar Of course but since kivy has not planned that behaviour we have to cheat a little, I will update my code with that

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following explanations, solutions, and example for details.

## Button - Border

Border information is in the format (bottom, right, top, left). Each value is in pixels. The border defaults to (16, 16, 16, 16). Use the following in kv File:

### Menu - Right Border On

```
border: (0, 16, 0, 0)
```

### Sub-menu - All Border Off

```
border: (0, 0, 0, 0)
```

## Dropdown Width

By default, the width of the dropdown will be the same as the width of the attached widget. Set auto-width to False if you want to provide your own width. Use the following in kv File.

### Increase Dropdown Width

```
auto-width: False
width: 150
```

## Text Alignment - Button/Label

By default the text image (texture) is only just large enough to contain the characters and is positioned in the center. The valign property will have no effect and halign will only have an effect if your text has newlines; a single line of text will appear to be centered even though halign is set to left (by default).

In order for the alignment properties to take effect, set the text_size, which specifies the size of the bounding box within which text is aligned. For instance, the following code binds this size to the size of the Button/Label, so text will be aligned within the widget bounds. This will also automatically wrap the text of the Button/Label to remain within this area.

The padding_x is horizontal padding of the text inside the widget box. It defaults to 0. The following code has a value of 5 so that the text is not close to the right border.

### Left Alignment

```
text_size: self.size
valign: "middle"
padding_x: 5
```

## Image - Decrease Space

AsyncImage means load an image asynchronously. It prevents your application from waiting until the image is loaded. If you want to display large images or retrieve them from URL’s, using AsyncImage will allow these resources to be retrieved on a background thread without blocking your application.

For example, if you want your image to be close to the image before it, you could do the following:

```
AsyncImage:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            texture: CoreImage("linux.png").texture
            size: self.width, self.height
            pos: self.x - 8, self.y
```

## Button/Label - Settings Repeated

Instead of having to repeat the same values for every button/label, we can just use a template instead as follow. The dynamic class, created just by the declaration of this rule, inherits from the Button class and allows us to change default values and create bindings for all its instances without adding any new code on the Python side.

### Template

```
    <DropdownButton@Button>:
        border: (0, 16, 0, 16)
        text_size: self.size
        valign: "middle"
        padding_x: 5
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '30dp'
        on_release: app.root.test
        background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
        color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1

    <MenuButton@Button>:
        text_size: self.size
        valign: "middle"
        padding_x: 5
        size : (60,30)
        size_hint : (None, None)
        background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
        color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
        border: (0, 16, 0, 0)

<CustDrop>:
    auto_width: False
    width: 150
    DropdownButton:
        text: 'Sub menu1 Test3'

    DropdownButton:
        text: 'Sub menu2 Test3'

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    BoxLayout:
        MenuButton:
            text: 'test1'

        MenuButton:
            text: 'test2'

        MenuButton:
            id: btn
            text: 'test3'
            on_release: dropdown.open(self)
```

## Examaple

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.lang import Builder


class CustDrop(DropDown):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustDrop, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.select('')


class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('main.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ExampleApp().run()
```

### main.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import CoreImage kivy.core.image.Image

<DropdownButton@Button>:
    border: (0, 16, 0, 16)
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5
    size_hint_y: None
    height: '30dp'
    #on_release: dropdown.select('')
    on_release: app.root.test
    background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
    color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1


<CustDrop>:
    auto_width: False
    width: 150
    DropdownButton:
        text: 'Sub menu1 Test3'

    DropdownButton:
        text: 'Sub menu2 Test3'

    DropdownButton:
        text: 'Sub menu3 Test3'

    DropdownButton:
        text: 'Fourth'


<MenuButton@Button>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5
    size : (60,30)
    size_hint : (None, None)
    background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
    color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
    border: (0, 16, 0, 0)


BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    #spacing : 10

    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        size_hint_y: 1

        MenuButton:
            text: 'test1'

        MenuButton:
            text: 'test2'

        MenuButton:
            id: btn
            text: 'test3'
            on_release: dropdown.open(self)

        CustDrop:
            id: dropdown

    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

            Color:
                rgb: (1,1,1)

        AsyncImage:
            source: "linux.png"     # '2.jpg'

        AsyncImage:
            source: "macosx.png"    # '4.jpg'

        AsyncImage:
            canvas:
                Rectangle:
                    texture: CoreImage("linux.png").texture    # '2.jpg'
                    size: self.width, self.height
                    pos: self.x - 8, self.y

        Label:
            size_hint_x: 22

    Label:
        size_hint_y: 18
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: MenuButton: id: btn4 text: 'test4' on_release: dropdown2.open(self) CustDrop: id: dropdown2 <CustDrop>: id: dropdown2 auto_width: False width: 150 DropdownButton: text: 'test1' DropdownButton: text: 'test2' DropdownButton: text: 'test3' DropdownButton: text: 'test4' Can you give me one more favour?i am creating one more menu with sub menu in above code.But it doesn't working properly and how to add one more level with navigate image  under 'Sub menu1 Test3' ex. test3>Sub menu1 Test3>Third level of sub menu.